# Get uilocale with javascript for a chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

i want to extract the uiLocale of the current browser of a chrome extension to make an ajax request to one page in a server.

I now i have the @@ui_locale but i cant't show it for example in an `alert();`

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you mean you want to get the locale from a chrome extension?
You could try to use something like `navigator.language`
or do you developing your own extension and want the locale?
In that case you use
`chrome.i18n.getMessage('@@ui_locale');`